# VBA code works in Access 2007 but doesn't work in Access 2010. Any ideas?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

My wife wrote the following code and it used to work fine for her when her organization used Access 2007. They just updated to Access 2010 and it no longer works. I am not familiar with Access at all but I suggested I'd present it to Stack to see if you guys can see anything straight off that won't work in Access 2010. Thanks in advance for any insights.

```
Private Sub Originating_Zone_AfterUpdate()

Dim EscortDB As DAO.Database

Dim rstBldgs As DAO.Recordset

Set EscortDB = CurrentDb()
Set rstBldgs = EscortDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT BuildingName FROM" & _
" ZoneBldgLookup WHERE ZoneLocation = '" & _
Forms!DateID!EscortIDSubform.Form.[Originating Zone] & _
"' ORDER BY BuildingName", [dbOpenDynaset])


rstBldgs.MoveLast

rstBldgs.MoveFirst

Do Until rstBldgs.EOF
Forms!DateID!EscortIDSubform.Form.[Pick Up Location].AddItem rstBldgs!BuildingName
rstBldgs.MoveNext
Loop

rstBldgs.Close


End Sub
```

**Update:** She got it working using the following code. Thanks for your help!

```
Private Sub Originating_Zone_AfterUpdate()

Dim sBuildList As String

sBuildList = ("SELECT BuildingName FROM" & _
" ZoneBldgLookup WHERE ZoneLocation = '" & _
Forms!DateID!EscortIDSubform.Form.[Originating Zone] & _
"' ORDER BY BuildingName")

Forms!DateID!EscortIDSubform.Form.[Pick Up Location].RowSource = sBuildList
Forms!DateID!EscortIDSubform.Form.[Pick Up Location].Requery

End Sub
```

Comment: Apparently that function used to populate a dropdown menu with a recordset created from a table based on the input in the previous dropdown list (ZoneBldgLookup). A chained selector. The second dropdown menu isn't getting populated at all anymore. It's not throwing any errors. It's 32 bit.

Comment: It's an Access application -- connection strings are meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @David-W-Fenton's suggestions, I think you should use a string variable to hold the SELECT statement.  Then you can Debug.Print it to the Immediate Window, copy it to a new query (in SQL View), and make sure it actually returns rows.

```
Dim strSql As String
strSql = "SELECT BuildingName FROM" & _
    " ZoneBldgLookup WHERE ZoneLocation = '" & _
    Forms!DateID!EscortIDSubform.Form.[Originating Zone] & _
    "' ORDER BY BuildingName"
Debug.Print strSql
Forms!DateID!EscortIDSubform.Form.[Pick Up Location].Rowsource = strSql
```

Also if this is code in the module of a form named DateID, you can replace `Forms!DateID` with the keyword `Me` (which is shorthand for "this form" ... the form which contains the code you're running).  That's not dramatically shorter, but `Me` will not need to be changed if the form is ever re-named.  Still not a big deal ... just one less detail you won't have to fiddle with down the road.

Comment: She got it working saying,  "I used the second guy's suggestion on the page, but I had to change the row source type to get it to work. It's possible that the row source type needed to be set differently in 2010 or something but instead of building a recordset, it worked to define the list as a string. Also, you need to requery after it's done so that it won't keep adding (i think. didn't try to not do it)." Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes, when you're assigning the rowsource of a combobox/listbox and it's a SQL string, it has to be a different type than when you're using .AddItem. I'm not sure about the requery, though -- setting the Rowsource makes a requery completely redundant.

Answer (score 3):

It's terrible code. Populating a dropdown list or listbox by walking a recordset and .AddItem is terribly inefficient. The whole thing can be done without code by simply assigning a SQL string to the Rowsource property of the combobox/listbox.

Now, clearly, the list changes based on the choices in the control to which this AfterUpdate event is attached, but all that means is that you assign the Rowsource in this event. Probably, all the above code can be replace with this:

```
  Forms!DateID!EscortIDSubform.Form.[Pick Up Location].Rowsource = "SELECT BuildingName FROM" & _
     " ZoneBldgLookup WHERE ZoneLocation = '" & _
     Forms!DateID!EscortIDSubform.Form.[Originating Zone] & _
     "' ORDER BY BuildingName"
```

I can't say what's wrong with the code not working (I suspect there's a sandbox mode/macro security issue going on), but it's way more lines of code than are needed.